# 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command after installing as administrator

Tags: node.js, express

I have already installed
`D:\TryOuts\nodejs>npm install express-generator -g` on my machine on administrator cmd. But when I run `D:\TryOuts\nodejs>express --view=hbs CodeSharing` I get this error:

```
'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What else should I do to make this work?

Comment: Have you checked, if express is inside the PATH? If not, it should work, after adding it to the PATH.

Comment: @Geshode, Where could it be installed Sir?

Comment: `npm root -g` this comand should show you the global install folder for npm

Comment: C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
Should I add this at the path Sir?

Comment: did you try to install `express` globally, rather than `express-generator`?

Comment: Yes I did Sir. The express is not recognized in my console but if I run it in my vs code terminal, it succeeds. So I just run it in from there.